# How to recover a question I accidently deleted on a google form yesterday?

Tags: google-forms

I don't know how I accidentally erased on of the questions of my Google Form yesterday and today when I click undo, it doesn't change anything on the form.

My Google form is linked to a Google Sheet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

##### No Version History

Version history isn't available in Forms. There’s no way to restore an old copy of your form as you would in Docs or Sheets.

You can click undo one or more times to undo changes if you catch the error while editing.